# Rails, form path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am trying to create many Lesson in one page using simple_form

The routes look like this

```
  resources :schools do
    resources :groups do
      resources :lessons, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
    end
  end

      school_group_lessons POST   /schools/:school_id/groups/:group_id/lessons(.:format)     lessons#create
   new_school_group_lesson GET    /schools/:school_id/groups/:group_id/lessons/new(.:format) lessons#new
```

The form currently look like this(tried many variations but I always get an error)

```
= simple_form_for school_group_lesson_path [school_id: 1, group_id: 1, Lesson.new]. remote: true, method: :post do |f|
```

The error I get for this is

> Can't assign to true 1, Lesson.new]. remote: true, method: :post do
>   |f|; ^
>   /home/panda/workspace/Schooled/app/views/lessons/_form.html.slim:18:
>   syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting end-of-input
>   _concat(("".freeze)); end; @output_buffer.safe_concat(( ^

which doesn't give me any clue on how to fix the problem... 
Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong :? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few mistakes I can point out for you

You have a **dot(.)** after `[school_id: 1, group_id: 1, Lesson.new]` which should be a **comma(,)**

This is wrong `[school_id: 1, group_id: 1, Lesson.new]`. You should give the **instances** of `school` and `group` as arguments along with `Lesson.new`

The **form path** is messed up. It should be either

```
= simple_form_for school_group_lessons_path(@school_instance,@group_instance,Lesson.new), remote: true, method: :post do |f|
```

**OR**

```
= simple_form_for [@school_instance,@group_instance,Lesson.new], remote: true, method: :post do |f|
```

Also notice that `school_group_lesson_path` should be `school_group_lessons_path`

Finally make sure you define the required `school` and `group` instances in the `controller#action`

Answer (score 0):

You have a period instead of a comma on this line:

```
= simple_form_for school_group_lesson_path [school_id: 1, group_id: 1, Lesson.new]. remote: true, method: :post do |f|
```

try:

```
= simple_form_for school_group_lesson_path(school_id: 1, group_id: 1, Lesson.new), remote: true, method: :post do |f|
```

Note: the correct usage of simple_form_for is something like:

```
simple_form_for @lesson do |f|
  f.input ....
end
```